# plgVmOnDisplayProductFEVM3 not triggering

Tags: joomla-4.x, virtuemart

I am trying to port some of my old plugins to latest VM, Joomla 4 and I have difficulties with couple of vmcustom plugins. The short version is, that the code I used to insert my needed code, namely something like this:

```
class plgVmCustomMyproduct extends vmCustomPlugin {
...
   function plgVmOnDisplayProductFEVM3($product,&$group) {
      vmdebug('myproduct: plgVmOnDisplayProductFEVM3 ');
....
   }

}
```

seems to not work. And I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.